# Use variable value on php webpage in separate javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, return

I have a server running which has a php function which returns true/false depending on input values. Currently I am just echoing the result on the page. I want to use this true/false in a to evaluate a condition in a javascript function running completely separately from the server.

Is there a javascript function I can use to get the text from a webpage and put it in a variable? I looked at the jquery load() function but this doesn't seem like it will work for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the output of the PHP script as simple as possible (a text response outputting only "true" or "false").

To send a text response (instead of an HTML response), you can use:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

You have to call this function before outputting anything.

Now, assuming you can access the output of the script at the URL http://www.example.com/webpage.php

```
if($.ajax({type: "GET", url: "http://www.example.com/webpage.php", async: false}).responseText == "true")
{
    // do something
}
else // "false"
{
    // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, we're nearly there, currently the output is <html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    true 
  </body>
</html>
I'm trying to find an option to just get the 'true' out, like is possible with .load()

Comment: is there a way to set up the php script so it send only the text in response to this request?

Comment: You need to remove the HTML tags from your code, and use the `header() ` function to specify that you're sending text (instead of HTML). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it seems like I need to put the php into it's own file

Comment: Oh just realised the html tags aren't necessary at all, I just deleted them all

Comment: The if wasn't working until I removed the == "true", the if will evaluate correctly without that. Thanks for your help

Comment: Wait, have you checked what happens if your PHP script returns "false"? Without the '== "true"', it would go into the 'if', not the 'else'.

Comment: In order to understand what's going on, you can do `alert($.ajax({type: "GET", url: "http://www.example.com/webpage.php", async: false}).responseText);`

Comment: Hmm so with the == 'true', the if always evaluates to false (even when the response is true), and if I remove the == 'true' then the if is always true, like you said. I guess I need to find some other way of comparing strings

Comment: Ok I changed the php script to return true and false (instead of "true" and "false") and now the comparison in the javascript is with 1 and it seems to work.

Comment: Maybe there were spaces, or newlines before/after the "true" or "false". In which case, adding `.trim()` after `responseText` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would work, but you might try using `document.body.innerHTML`. It gets you the innerHTML from the body element from the document (which, in your case, should be a true or false string).

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to use jQuery to get the echoed out result of your php you can do:

```
     var whatever = "<?php echo $result ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP/HTML (assuming you have a function named "yourFunction" that returns a boolean):

```
<div id="your_id">
    <?php echo yourFunction()?'true':'false';?>
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript

```
if($('#your_id').text() == "true")
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

Comment: Like I said the php is running on a server and the javascript is running locally. They are separate.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it like html, update your doc to add a tag around the result.  "true" at which point your almost using XML.

You should be able to get the raw response.  I usually don't recommend consuming raw text tho as people could inject malicious js into the response.